# How to use multiple criteria with Regexreplace in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to correct the number/expression of room numbers that are entered by users with the following:

1- If the number contains ( / or \ or _ ), it will be replaced with "-".

2- If the number contains "iso" or "Bed", it should be removed or replaced with "".

The sample sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U-daD0CEPRLoCP7xCLT9bSMK9yN3ll8QQQfNk7-OZDs/edit#gid=1418057437.

Column A is to be entered by a user.

Column B is the result of arrayformula. The arrayformula is in B3 Cell. I couldn't add more than two regular expressions. Like, `("\|_|/")`.. what works is two only `("\|_")`.

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE((ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(UPPER(A3:A),("ISO|BED"),""))),("\|_"),"-"))`

It seems also complicated using two arrayformula functions in the same line.

What I want the result to be is: a number with "-" separator only. (I typed the expected results in Column C in order to modify the arrayformula to produce same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash `\` is used to escape the following character to give it a special meaning. For example, `\d` means any digit 0-9. To get a backslash, you need to escape it, as in `\\`. To make the match case-insensitive, use the `(?i)` flag. Try this:

```
=arrayformula( regexreplace( regexreplace(A3:A, "(?i)iso|bed", ""), "[-/\\]", "-" ) )
```

See:

- https://regexone.com/
- https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

You only need one `arrayformula()` wrapper to array enable all of the formula.